# Security issues in java spring

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am curious about the security parts of java spring.

I have taken a snippet from this website teaching on how to do a login system using database.

However, i am concerned about certain parts regarding the security issues.

```
<h1>Spring Security Login Form (Database Authentication)</h1>

<div id="login-box">

    <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
        <div class="error">${error}</div>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
        <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='loginForm'
      action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
              value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />

    </form>
</div>
```

As this form will be deployed on a server, and users will log in from their PC. However, this would mean that the data would not be encrypted. Pardon my weak explanation of my problem as i am still new to this java spring environment. I am concerned about the sending of data from the user PC to the server for authentication in the database.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Is there anyway to encrypt the packets from the user PC to the server or would this be handled by tomcat servers?

Comment: Configure Tomcat to use https and you'll get your encryption.

Comment: This has nothing to do with spring or jave but with HTML/HTTP in general. A form gets submitted as is. Now you could do some encrypting with JavaScript but what would that add? The code is on the client, you need a two-way encryption/decryption algorithm it doesn't add anything. As @AndreiStefan already pointed out you should use https to submit this form (or any secured/sensitive information for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use SSL to make request to your server over HTTP, data in your request/response will not be encrypted. To make encrypted communication between your browser and web-server you need to configure SSL in your tomcat.  [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) link will be helpful in explaining SSL configuration in apache tomcat.

Spring-security has nothing to do with how data are transferred over HTTP communication, It's more concern with your web application resources access. Like which URL, resources are accessible by whom (i.e based on ROLE).